# Has anyone figured out a keyboard shortcut to globally strikethrough selected text in any OS X app?

Tags: keyboard, text-editor, shortcut-menu, formatting

We have <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bold, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to italicise, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to underline, but we don't (as far as I can tell) have a shortcut to strikethrough selected text in **any** OS X rich editor.

I added a keyboard shortcut into System Preferences, but that way doesn't work very consistently. I also tried using TextExpander, but it doesn't support rich text formatting.

Has anyone come up with a way to do this?

Answer (score 15):

Hey I just came across this question because today I just started to use Stickies as a To-Do list for things I need to finish over the day and I also wanted to have that feature that you ***strikethrough*** items or text you are done with…

I think an easy workaround for this is that you have lets say 3 items, then you go to mark your first item with the *strikethrough* from the Fonts panel and then select that all the item and go to **Font > Copy Style** (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then because it is copied in the Stickies app, after, anytime you use the shortcut <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (**Paste Style**) over a selected item it will paste the strikethrough style anytime later on the app, even if you have any other copied item in your clipboard.

Comment: this is amazing and I had no idea this functionality existed. thank you!

Comment: Interesting one but it will also copy other style properties of previous text like Bold, Italic, Color, etc.

Comment: Yes, it will copy all text style properties. To do ONLY strikethrough, you'll have to go to the Fonts dialog (Cmd+T) and select the strikethrough style. You can also set the color of the strikethrough there. When you have some text with all the text properties you like, then you can use Cmd+Opt+C to copy that set for easy pasting with Cmd+Opt+V.

Answer (score 8):

Shortcuts created in System Preferences will only work globally with applications that have matching Strikethrough options in their menu. This is not a feature that all rich text editors provide, thus the inconsistencies you experienced.

Nevertheless, TextExpander does support rich text formatting. When creating a new snippet click the "Content" header above the snippet and select "Formatted Text, Pictures." You could use this to store a small sample of strikethrough text to use the formatting of. This is sort of a painful workaround, but it should suffice in the majority of applications. You will probably encounter a few exceptions where this will not work.

The simplest solution is built into Mountain Lion. Select any text in a rich text editor and `CTRL+Click` (right-click) on it. Select the Font>Styles
[image: Selecting Font Styles from Context Menu]
A new menu pops up. Select "Favorite Styles" and then select "Struck through" from the drop down menu. Now click Apply. 
[image: Favorite Styles Menu]

Your text will now be struck through. Keep in mind this Font menu may not appear in all rich text editors and others may not display struck through text at all.

Answer (score 6):

an even quicker way is to use the upper left corner with with the little drop down menu with the paragraph symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's an AppleScript that automatically opens the Font panel, applies the strikethrough and closes the font panel, in less than a second.

You can edit the number in the line "tell menu 2" to "tell menu 3" to get double strikethrough. With "tell menu 1" you can remove a strikethrough.

I've created a Macro Group for Stickies in Keyboard Maestro, and have one macro of the following code to apply the strikethrough, and one to remove it.

[image: Keyboard Maestro Sticky Strikethrough Shortcut]

**Applescript:**

```
set theBundle to ((path to library folder from system domain as string) & "Frameworks:AppKit.framework:") as «class furl»
set fonts_loc to localized string "Fonts" from table "FontManager" in bundle theBundle

try
    with timeout of 5 seconds
        tell application "System Events"
            tell (first application process whose frontmost is true)
                if not (exists window fonts_loc) then
                    keystroke "t" using command down -- show fonts window
                end if
                repeat until exists window fonts_loc
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                tell window fonts_loc to tell toolbar 1 to tell group 3
                    tell menu button 1
                        click it
                        repeat until exists menu 1
                            delay 0.1
                        end repeat
                        tell menu 2
                            -- number of menu item --> {"None", "Simple", "Double", missing value, "Color"}
                            click menu item 1
                        end tell
                    end tell -- menu button 1
                end tell -- window…
                keystroke "t" using command down -- hide fonts window
            end tell -- process
        end tell -- "System Events"
    end timeout
end try
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> works in MS Excel for Mac 2011.

Comment: This only applies to Excel, not system-wide as the question was asking about

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can cross through individual characters in Safari and other Mac docs by:

1 In Safari (or other) Toolbar, Click 'Edit' > 'Special Characters'

2 In pop-up's 'Search' box type: "combining long stroke overlay" and click on the '-' that   comes up under the 'Unicode' heading at the bottom of the central column in the box

3 Click 'Add to Favourites' box

4 The Special Characters pop-up can be left open and dragged to a convenient area of the screen whilst completing Safari docs etc (I use it for writing foreign language rules in Quizlet). Type the character you wish to show crossed out, then double click the '-' character in the Favourites section of the pop-up to strike through

Answer (score 1):

This one's what I do as a workaround.

- Write a "struck-through text" on Word.
- Copy and paste that "struck-through text" to the sticky note.
- Format the newly pasted "struck-through text" the way you want on your
  sticky note.
- Select the "struck-through text" and click Opt+Cmd+C (or click Font >
  copy style)
- Highlight the item you want to strike through.
- Click Opt+Cmd+V (or click Font > paste style)

Tedious at first but works fine after.
:)

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem and figured out you could if you went to the side bar (the format tab in Pages) and then clicked on character styles then held down strikethrough and liked shortcut you could set F1–F9 as shortcuts for the strikethrough effect!

Comment: This only applies to Pages, not system-wide as the question was asking about

Answer (score -4):

Shortcut key is <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: This does not work in TextEdit on OS X 10.9. Is there a specific application you are using?

Comment: This only applies to Microsoft Office apps, not system-wide as the question was asking about