# Notes 4.0 (El Capitan) strikethrough option removed

Tags: macos, notes.app

Does anyone know how to apply a strikethrough to text in the new Notes app? It seems the option has been removed entirely from all font menus, contextual menus and even the font palette!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yeah, the option is a bit well hidden, dunno why.
Its called **Struck through**  instead of strikethrough

To get the text formatting in **Notes 4.0**

[image]

1) Make a text selection for the *struck through*, right click on it

2) Select **Fonts** then **Styles**

[image: select the thext for struck through]

3) Use the **Style Browser** or whatever that is called 
to check the **Favourite Styles** and then select **Struck Through** from the dropdown list. Tada!

[image]

**Wow.** That was ***really easy*** and accessible, right? Why not add 
another step since all that makes a lot of sense. I guess, this time 
Apple struck through the UX.

Here one close-up of the option. I think one can make a Keyboard 
shortcut that will make this more ehh sane to use. Maybe there is
one already.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, they don't use lists? Took me a while to figure that out. Will be probably corrected with the next update ;)

Comment: What a horribly obscure place to hide a formatting feature that lots of people use.  I vaguely remember there being a shortcut in the past using the "-" character in combination with other control characters that would strikethrough selected text.  That, however, doesn't seem to exist anymore.  Would love if they put this in a better place or assigned a shortcut. SMH.

Comment: Apple definitely "struck" out on this.

Comment: Notes 4.5 has improved with right-click (context menu) -> Font -> Strikethrough. Two clicks. Or you can choose Format -> Font -> Strikethrough from the application menu.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that ⇧⌘L is intended to replace striking items through. This provides you with a very nice list that you can check and uncheck items. It is annoying that they would bury the strikethrough, but I do enjoy the checklist a lot more, especially when viewing the notes on my iPhone or iPad.

Answer (score 7):

To add on to PJJ's answer, you can more quickly strike through text with the copy style keyboard shortcut. Select some already struck through text, <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (**Format > Font > Copy Style**). Then select the text you want to strike through and <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (**Format > Font > Paste Style**).

From: [Has anyone figured out a keyboard shortcut to globally strikethrough selected text in any OS X app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59502/has-anyone-figured-out-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-globally-strikethrough-selected-te)

Comment: This is cool. Very useful for even other formatting cases. Now I kept a snippet of strikethrough text and leave it as a template for your method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notes checklists are way cool, but that's only one of many uses for <strike>strikeout</strike> (errrr .... "struck out").

Answer (score 0):

The question has probably been answered, but as a side note, there's something nice you can do; [assign a keyboard shortcut to strikethrough](https://appuals.com/how-to-strikethrough-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-on-a-mac/).